# For Ruby on Rails, is Devise almost the de facto choice? Is there any option at all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I hear so much about Devise for being the log in system of choice (user authentication system) for Rails 2.3.x or 3.0.x.  Is there even a second choice at all, or is Devise simply the best gem for this purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Right now it looks that way. Take a look at [ruby toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication.html) and compare. The other popular authentication system I know of is Authlogic but it doesn't look like it's being actively worked on. Last commit was 5 months ago and their open issues on github are piling up.

Devise on the other hand was committed to hours ago, has 15 open issues (at the time of this post) and is being adopted quick by those in the rails community. Plus, it's written by an active contributor to the rails core, Jose Valim. I'd say it's the de facto choice right now for rails authentication.

Comment: +1 for Devise. Something that makes it special is that it is based on the Warden library for Rack authentication. This is useful if you later add components to your application that are Sinatra or Pure Ruby based rather than Rails you can maintain a single session for all of your applications instead of having to log into each separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can always roll your own simple auth framework. Devise was written to solve a problem. If you have a problem with Devise then you can write something to solve that problem. Such is the nature of innovation.

Meta: I'm not trying to be snarky, I genuinely believe that you shouldn't fix what ain't broke and that stuff what's broke oughta be fixed.